# how to create solution file .sln ,.csproj ,assemblyinfo.cs dynamically

Tags: c#

I am creating code generation tool as windows forms application in visual studio 2010 in framework 4.0.

I want to build .csproj file, assemblyinfo.cs and .sln file dynamically including the some class files I have created so that when I click on this .sln file it is opened as project with all class files that I have generated.

It means that when I click on generatesolution button, a new project should be created with all folders automatically, that are created when we create new project from visual studio.

Please help me.

Comment: plz try to help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off using Visual Studio's automation capabilities rather than trying to generate the files yourself - there's an article on MSDN "[Controlling the Solution and Its Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t51cz75w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)" which gives an overview of the process of generating a olution, though it's a bit short on detail: there's also sample code in the [documentation for the solution2 interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.solution2.aspx) which shows how to create a console app solution, and an article on [How to Programatically create projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228767.aspx).

Hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

To create a project programatically, you can use  **Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project** ([MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.aspx)) and for the solution just use **EnvDTE** ([MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solution.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

What is a solution ? I think a  file which  contains references and properties .

So what is the project file , It has some information about the forms and classes.

Basically we can write into a .sln file something like this :

```
Solution Name : Sol1
Projects      : 1
References    : System,System.Text,System.Linq
```

and for a project file :

```
Forms Count     : 4
Classes         : 8
Folders         : 2
Resources       : 0
Silver light    : N
Web             : N
Type            : Windows Application
Directory       : C:\Dir
Framework       : 4
Parent Solution: Sln1
```

Or you can create  data structures(class) for solution and project.

But it's better to Contact MSDN and get their own data structre and headers for .sln file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create a plain vanilla solution/project using Visual Studio with the bare minimum you need, then use the files created as a template for your code generation procedure.

You would need to change the project files to reference your generated files though. A .csproj file is just XML so it should be quite easier to alter that - look at how it adds sources files as a guideline. A .sln file would be a bit trickier to edit as that is a custom format, but I guess some kind of string replace/RegEx could work.